Is every endomorphism of the folded cube of order $5$ invertible?
Let $\square^4$ denote the $4$-dimensional hypercube, regarded as the convex hull of $\{0, 1\}^4 \subset {\mathbb{R}}^4$. Regard $\square^4$ as a graph where two vertices are adjacent if and only if they are joined by an edge. Add 8 more edges, by declaring in addition that each vertex $(x,y,z,w) \in \{0, 1\}^4$ of $\square^4$ is adjacent to $(1 - x, 1 - y, 1-z,1-w)$. The resulting graph with $2^4 = 16$ vertices and $4\times 2^{4-1} +8 = 40$ edges is known as the folded cube of order $5$.
Is every endomorphism of the folded cube of order 5 necessarily invertible? An endomorphism of the folded cube of order 5 is a function $f$ from its set of vertices to itself such that whether $(x, y, z, w)$ is adjacent to $(x', y', z', w')$, then $f(x, y, z ,w)$ is also adjacent to $f(x', y', z', w')$.

Yes, every endomorphism is invertible.
If $f$ is an endomorphism, it must send every $5$-cycle to another $5$-cycle. (In general, an endomorphism must send an odd cycle to an odd closed walk, but every odd closed walk contains an odd cycle; the folded cube of order $5$ does not contain any triangles, so the odd closed walk must be a $5$-cycle.) In particular, $f$ must be injective on every $5$-cycle. Any two vertices in the graph lie on a common $5$-cycle, so $f$ is globally injective, and therefore invertible.
